# How to show 8 videos on PC screen and 4 videos on Mobile screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have 8 videos shown on my computer but I want it to only show 4 when working on mobile devices.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? try to give a minimal code what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css with [`media query`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and hide(`display:none`) on mobile `width` the video you want:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .video-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>video 1</div>
  <div>video 2</div>
  <div>video 3</div>
  <div>video 4</div>
  <div class="video-mobile">video 5</div>
  <div class="video-mobile">video 6</div>
  <div class="video-mobile">video 7</div>
  <div class="video-mobile">video 8</div>
</div>
```